# React Native Victory Chart hide axis line but keep tick values format issues

Tags: react-native, graph, victory-charts

I managed to remove both Y and X-axis lines but it caused an issue with the X-axis date values. Previously VictoryChart would nicely render the X-axis dates into months, days or years depending on the amount of data. Now it's a mess.

I did try to add this line to `VictoryAxis` but said invalid date

```
tickFormat = {d => new Date(d.date_time)}
```

See result

[image]

Code:

```
export function VictoryAreaChart({ chartData, yName }) {
  return (
    <VictoryChart>
      <VictoryLine
        animate={{ easing: 'exp' }}
        domainPadding={{y: 5}}
        height={150}
        interpolation="natural"
        x={d => new Date(d.date_time)}
        y={yName}
        data={chartData}
        style={{
          data: {
            stroke: '#4E54C8',
            strokeWidth: 2
          }
        }}
        data={chartData}
        events={[
          {
            target: "data",
            eventHandlers: { 
            }
          }
        ]}
      />
      <VictoryAxis
        style={{ axis: {stroke: { fill: "none" } }}}
      />
      <VictoryAxis dependentAxis
        style={{ axis: {stroke: { fill: "none" } }}}
      />
    </VictoryChart>
  );
}
```

Previously how X axis looked like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `tickFormat` in `VictoryAxis` and write a function to format the date display if necessary.

```
<VictoryAxis
  tickFormat={item => formatDate(item)} 
  style={{ axis: {stroke: { fill: "none" } }}}
/>
```